# Touch ID Alert Button Tint

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to change the tint color of the buttons on Touch ID Alert view using the usual tactics e.g.

```
window?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
UIView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

These do not seem to work for the Touch ID alert. For a regular alert created with a `UIAlertViewController` the tint of buttons can alternatively be set by something like the following:

```
alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

However, that requires access to the view controller which you don't get when you use `context.evaluatePolicy...`

I know this is possible because it can be seen in the Notes app (not enough reputation to post image). However, I'm wondering if this was achieved by some undocumented API or ugly workaround.